# how to specify resolution in OS X Core Graphics bitmap context?

Tags: macos, core-graphics

I've been looking through the documentation for OS X Core Graphics, but I can't see anything that specifies the dpi resolution. 
How do I create a bitmap context at 300 dpi?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bitmap context has no "resolution" (in the sense of pixels per inch, or per whatever unit of physical distance). It's just a grid of pixels — so it does have the other common meaning of "resolution" meaning width and height in pixels, which you provide when using the [`CGBitmapContextCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455939-cgbitmapcontextcreate?language=objc) function (or the [`init(data:width:height:bitsPerComponent:bytesPerRow:space:bitmapInfo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455939-init) initializer in Swift 3).

Concepts like dots per inch or pixels per point come into play only when you're writing a bitmap to an output file or displaying it on screen. And the way to do that, of course, depends on what you're doing. Some tips:

- For writing a TIFF file, write DPI values in the file metadata using the `kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution` and `kCGImagePropertyTIFFYResolution` with [`CGImageDestination`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/imageio/1666386-cgimagedestination) (see also [Working with Image Destinations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/ikpg_dest/ikpg_dest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH219-SW3)). There are similar metadata keys for other formats, like `kCGImagePropertyPNGXPixelsPerMeter`.
- For displaying on screen, see [High Resolution Guidelines for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH1-SW1).